# How do I delete my Google Cloud Platform Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 2 cloud accounts and only need one, how do I delete or cancel my account so I do not have to pay for the one?

Comment: Do you mean "account" as in email or project?

Comment: I assume you're referring to delete your Google Cloud projects ?

Comment: Neither of the answers explain how to "delete" the account. Yes, you can "disable" the billing, but can you delete the account? I've wasted a lot of time already back and forth with the terrible customer service at Google, so far they aren't closing anything--supposedly to "protect my privacy." I will be following the progress here.

Comment: Seems this question now factors into GDPR compliance: "The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller the erasure of personal data concerning him or her without undue delay and the controller shall have the obligation to erase personal data without undue delay where one of the following grounds applies:
the personal data are no longer necessary in relation to the purposes for which they were collected or otherwise processed;"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By "account", I assume that you mean "Google Cloud Platform project", because a "Google Cloud Platform Account" is the same as a Google account, assuming you're referring to user credentials. You don't pay for such an account; you only pay for the resources you use, which are attached to a project.

You can easily delete a project from [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) — once you delete it, it will delete any contained resources and you won't be charged for them.

---

Note that a project will not cost you anything if it is not consuming any resources.

Thus, there's no need to delete or cancel either your email accounts or projects. As soon as you stop using resources within a particular project, you will stop being charged for those resources.

Comment: That is true yet your credit card details are linked to that account and in theory it may be breached - hence the functionality of deleting should have been available.

Comment: @avip — if you want, you can delete your project and email account, but you can also just delete the billing info and still keep your Google Cloud Platform project and Google Account. These are all separate things.

Comment: While this is again correct, the fact remains that google gives me no option to permanently *delete* my billing info. I can 'close' it, but I cannot _delete_ it. I trust google with my data, but still find this lack somewhat disturbing...

Comment: I agree that it is disturbing. I have a debit card from one of our company's purchasing managers no longer on our project that is still attached to my cloud account. I've had over a dozen communications with Google billing support, and all that has happened is they closed all my billing accounts to verify the one, ironically, that I'm trying to remove. My server went down, and it remains down. For anyone reading this - if you have any problems or doubts about Google's billing practice or customer service (or lack thereof), run the other way and go to AWS. I sure wish I had.

Comment: @Joe – I'm sorry you didn't have a great experience. Could you please reach out to me with more details? You can find me on LinkedIn and GitHub (my email address is in my commits: use the [`.patch` trick](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets) to find it from any of my PRs).

Comment: @avip – Thank you for the feedback on deleting billing accounts; I understand your frustration. The [help page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) says (under **Close billing account**): _"Billing accounts cannot be deleted."_ I am looking into what we can do to improve this; I hope to have an update soon.

Comment: I had been away for 3 months so when I finally got home and checked my credit card statements, to my surprise I saw google deducting money from my credit card!!

I had setup 2 projects that both were not active, and not being used.

There is no way of deleting the account, so I deleted the projects.
Yet another example.

Comment: @Beezer — Google Cloud Platform *projects* don't have fees themselves, only cloud resources do. Your Google account bill should have an itemized list of resources for which you were charged for and an amount for each, e.g., Compute Engine virtual machines, Cloud Storage buckets/objects, App Engine instances, etc. so you should be able to see what specifically caused the billing.

Comment: @Beezer — if you'd like me to look into your issue further, please get in touch with me via (my GitHub username) [at] google.com

Comment: @PJBrunet – what are you trying to delete? Above, I linked to [instructions for closing a billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) – is that insufficient? What else are you trying to do?

Comment: I have two problems with this answer. #1 the hidden cost may come in the form of annoying emails, which can't be blocked as spam if you use Gmail. For example, I get get "invoices" all the time saying that I don't owe anything. #2 It's a good habit to clean up after yourself, especially data. For example, people leave a trail of data thinking it's harmless, then a hacker or disgruntled employee finds some attack vector, like the time Matt Mullenweg accidentally published an important password in a random WordPress tutorial. Maybe it's not even your data to leave carelessly behind.

Answer (score 18):

1. "Disable" the billing. You can find the partly-accurate instructions here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en
2. Find the "IAM" panel in the hamburger menu, where you have to copy-paste the names of the services (random numbers and letters) and then wait several seconds for the confirm button to turn from gray to black. For some reason, you have to delete these one at a time, in a specific order. (Note: Even if you didn't use the service, you should double-check this, because there was a lot here that I did not create.)
3. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects and trashbin the projects. Again, there was a project here called "numeric-abbey-xxxxxx" that I did not create, nor did I accept any invitations or join any groups.
4. To "close" your billing account:

   a. Go to the Cloud Platform Console https://console.cloud.google.com/

   b. Hamburger menu: select Billing.

   c. Select the billing account name. (Do this twice.)

   d. Click "Close billing account."

   e. Type "close" to confirm.

Note: Google will not entirely "delete" your billing information:

> "Upon checking, your billing account is still active. You will need to close it to prevent notifications being sent to your email. We cannot delete the details on your billing account for auditing
>   purposes. Though rest assured that we take privacy very seriously.
>   Once your billing account is closed, all the information will be
>   encrypted and moved to a cold storage."

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en

For some industry perspective, in terms of complexity, this is very unusual. Both as a consumer, developer, working at ISPs, I have never seen such a complex process to close a business account in my 20+ years of hosting. (Academia is another story.) This is not meant to be disparaging or a "rant." Depending on the type of work that you do, maybe complexity is exactly what you're looking for. I believe it's important to know what you're getting into ahead of time.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel that you need to delete each of the service accounts individually – they are owned by the project, so deleting the project will cascade and delete all resources in the project, including any resources provisioned in the project (storage buckets, VMs, etc.) as well as service accounts. Are you saying that you've seen service accounts outlive their parent project's lifetime?

Comment: Regarding a project you did not create: someone can create a project and add you as an owner, but you have to accept the invitation (which is sent by email) before you can access it. Has anyone invited you to join their project? If you haven't yet deleted that project, you can see who the other owners are and chat with them about it.

Comment: Re: "What is IAM?" (from revision history): if you visit cloud.google.com, at the upper-right corner is a search box. If you type in "iam" there and press `<Enter>` you'll get these search results: https://cloud.google.com/s/results/?q=iam which will tell you that IAM stands for "Identify and Access Management", it's a standard term in the industry, and it will point you to the docs for it. If you search for IAM on google.com, you'll see Google's as well as other companies' documentation for the same topic.

Comment: The many email addresses you see in your project's IAM page are service accounts, more info here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts

Comment: @PJBrunet – another way you may have access to a project is if you are a member of a mailing list (via Google Groups) and that mailing list was made a member or owner of a Google Cloud project. In that case, every subscriber gets access to the project, as stated on the IAM page. See if there are any mailing lists which are members of the project, and see if you are a member of any of those lists. Also, one can add an entire domain to a project as a "member" and everyone on that domain gets access to that project.

Comment: Misha, you might want to ask a separate question on that topic. We could easily break this into several questions due to the complexity of the problem. I'm not aware of any Google Groups or domain members that would be relevant. This page is about deleting the Google Cloud Platform account, which I am still working on. Google Tech Support is still finding more steps for me to follow, which I must say is hilarious. Apparently "disabling" my billing isn't enough, and there's some additional step required to put my billing into "cold storage." I'll write a longer update once I have more details.

Comment: Finally deleted in 2018? The saga continues. "Action required
Dear Google customer,

You are receiving this email because you are a Google Cloud Platform, Firebase, or API customer.

Your billing account (xxxx) has been terminated for failure to provide a valid payment instrument or for not making all overdue payments within 30 days of notice. In addition the related Project(s) and/or Service(s) have been terminated.

If you wish to request reinstatement of your billing account and to pay all amounts past due and to update your account with valid payment information, follow this link:"

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to your developer account
2. select project from drop down
3. go top right corner click three dots icon
4. select "project settings"
5. click on "shut down"

Answer (score 6):

This answer is for anyone who arrives at this question wanting to close a billing account and delete their credit card information from it. To delete all my credit cards, I had to close my billing account first.

1. Go to Billing (in the lefthand sidebar, or also https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) and choose the right billing account you want to close.
2. Go to Billing > Account Management, and click the "X" on the top banner to close this billing account. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#close_a_billing_account
3. In Billing > Payment Method, remove your credit card.

Before, I was trying to do 3 before 2, but I kept getting an error requiring another credit card be added. I had to do step 2, then 3 worked.

Comment: click the "X" on the top banner . There is no such thing.

Comment: @BlueClouds  There are two entrances to the "Billing" page. One does not have the "X" on the top banner, the other entrance does have (actually on the top second banner). I had struggled for a few hours and somehow accidentally got into the right entrance from the main hamburger menu (the GCP navigation menu), where the "Billing" item has a ">"  for a next-level menu. From the next-level menu, everything worked fine. But in most time the "Billing" item in the main menu does not have a ">" to the next-level menu. I show the figures as a new answer just FYI, since comment does not allow figures.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible it is like a chicken and egg situation.

1. You need to close the project
2. **you can go to [Google payments](https://myaccount.google.com/payments-and-subscriptions)(not google cloud) and keep clicking until you find 'close' billing/payment.**
3. Now the last part is the payments profile in google cloud. That will remain(mystery). If you click contact customer, you will be taken to the project page and suprise! you have no project so cannot contact customer.
4. All the documentation says there is an option in google payments profile to close it but there isn't!
5. And then while you wait wondering what is going on, your google cloud billing has disappeared!! So #2 did the trick and you just need to wait a bit.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a true answer, but a finding of mine that might be useful to others. At least it was critical for me to solve the billing account problem.)

According to Google's instructions "[close_a_billing_account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#close_a_billing_account)", when you go to Main navigation menu > Billing > Account Management, you can click the "X" on the top to close the billing account.

But many people cannot find the "X" in the "Billing" page (or a "X" for irrelevant thing like "removing filters"). I had the same problem, as shown in Figure 1.

[image]
After struggling with GCP console for a while, I accidentally hit the right entrance to the "Billing" page, which showed different UI from the one above. I successfully removed my billing account from there. The page after the billing account removal is given below in Figure 2. It has a frame layout, where I marked the place of the original "X", which is replaced by an "Undo" flag after the account removal.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't remember how I got to the right "Billing" page (i.e., the Figure 2).  I only remember that the "Billing" item (from the GCM main navigation hamburger menu) has a ">" leading to a next-level menu. In the next-level menu, everything worked fine. But often times the "Billing" item in the main menu does not have a ">" to the next-level menu. When you click it, it goes to the UI of Figure 1, rather than the frame layout as in Figure 2.

Anyone knows how to go to the Figure 2 Billing page please feel free to comment so as to make the answer really useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard page
2. select your project
3. select hamberger button
4. I AM ADMIN menu
5. Select Setting
   [image: menu image]
6. Select Shutdown
7. Type Project ID in text box

[image: shutdown image]
finish

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To remove the latest credit card, it's impossible to do it yourself with the UI.
Because if you have only one credit card registered, the only option is to replace the card with another one.

Then you need to end up **by sending an email to the support**.
Ask them to remove the card manually (seriously...I will hesitate multiple time before giving my credit card to google again!)

Answer (score -2):

Shutting down a project in the console releases all resources used within the project.

To shut down a project:

1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console.
2. Open the console menu  Gallery Menu  on the top left and select IAM & Admin, then select All projects.
3. Find the name or project ID of the project you want to shut down, then click DELETE PROJECT. A confirmation screen describing what will happen appears.
4. To confirm, enter your project ID and click Shut down.

Shutting down a project stops all billing and traffic serving, shuts down any Google Cloud Platform App Engine applications, and terminates all Compute Engine instances. All project data associated with Google Cloud and Google APIs services becomes inaccessible.

Google is charging for resource usage. If you delete a project, your project will not use any resource and you will not get charged.

Look at the link for reference : 
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en&ref_topic=6158848